# Build failed in Android Studio Hedgehog

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I just created new application in `Android Studio Hedgehog | 2023.1.1` using `Empty Activity` template. Immediately I'm getting this error.

[image]

I'm using Android Studio Hedgehog,

[image]

Any advice will be highly useful.

Comment: You'll need to show at least some of your build.gradle for anyone to be able to help. Perhaps the repositories, and plugins sections.